# How to make yii2 chartjs horizintal

Tags: php, yii2, chart.js

I'm using [2amigos/yii2-chartjs-widget](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-chartjs-widget) to draw charts and everything works fine except the chart orientation, I want to make it horizontal. like this:
[image: need orintation]

My code is:

```
<?=ChartJs::widget([
                    'type' => 'bar',
                    'id'=> 'agent'.$index,
                    'options' => [
                        'indexAxis'=> 'y',
                        'responsive'=> true,
                        'height' => 200,
                        'width' => 400
                    ],
                    'data' => [
                        'radius' =>  "90%",
                        'labels' => array_keys($productschart),
                        'datasets' => [
                            [
                                'data' =>array_values($productschart),
                                'label' => '',
                                'backgroundColor' => Charts::Colors(count($productschart)),
                                'borderColor' =>  [
                                    '#fff',
                                    '#fff',
                                    '#fff'
                                ],
                                'borderWidth' => 1,
                                'hoverBorderColor'=>["#999","#999","#999"],
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                ]);
                ?>
```

even after adding 'indexAxis' => 'y', the chart is still vertical like this:
[image: current chart]

Answer (score 1):

the solution is using  'type' => 'horizontalBar' instead of 'type' => 'bar'